# How to handle touch outside the view in Android?

Tags: android, gmail, undo

I've found implementation of ["Undo Bar"](https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/undobar) used in Gmail application for Android. "UndoBar" is basically a View that is displayed on top of the layout.

Unfortunately it's not complete - it has no functionality of dismissing bar by touching screen outside the bar.

I've implemented `FrameLayout` that overrides `onInterceptTouchEvent` to handle bar dismissing but touching Action Bar does nothing.

Is there any way to handle such events from Action Bar?

Below there is an Image with "UndoBar"shown. What I want to achieve to handle touch in Action bar represented by red dot.

[image]

Comment: "it has no functionality of dismissing bar by touching screen outside the bar". Can you explain what a "bar" is ?

Comment: It is just a view, exactly it is a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I do not understand. You want to change its visibility ? Can you add relevant snippets of code?

Comment: No, I want to handle touch outside this view, specifically in ActionBar. I have small view and activity with action bar. In Gmail application when You delete message an "UndoBar" appears, when You click anywhere - action bar, background etc. UndoBar disappears. I would like to have the same behavior.

Comment: Implement a scroll listener on the `ListView` then on scroll call `hideUndoBar(true)` that should do it. It's not literally a touch, but the slightest amount of scrolling will remove the undo bar.

Answer (score 8):

Try to override dispatchTouchEvent of your activity.

```
dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

     int x= event.getRawX();
     int y= event.getRawY();


         if(/*check bounds of your view*/){
          // set your views visiblity to gone or what you want. 
         }
      //for prevent consuming the event.
      return super().dispatchTouchEvent(event);    
}
```

**update**

```
dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

     int x= event.getRawX();
     int y= event.getRawY();

      return super().dispatchTouchEvent(event)||[YourView].onTouch(event);    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To catch touch events for the whole screen including the ActionBar add a view to the Window.

```
View overlayView = new View(this);
WindowManager.LayoutParams p = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
p.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
p.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL;
p.token = overlayView.getWindowToken();
overlayView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        // Get the action bar
        int actionBarHeight = actionBar.getHeight();
        if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            && (event.getRawY() < actionBarHeight)) {
            // Touch inside the actionBar so let's consume it
            // Do something
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
mWindowManager.addView(overlayView, p);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how you get windowToken from a layout that did't get attach yet?! overlayView

Answer (score 2):

You should just override Activity's dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent) method

---

Look at this example of dismissing indefinite Snackbar

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var snackbar: Snackbar? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    // show indefinite snackbar
    snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinator_layout, "Hello world!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).apply {
        show()
    }
}

/**
 * On each touch event:
 * Check is [snackbar] present and displayed
 * and dismiss it if user touched anywhere outside it's bounds
 */
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    // dismiss shown snackbar if user tapped anywhere outside snackbar
    snackbar?.takeIf { it.isShown }?.run {
        val touchPoint = Point(Math.round(ev.rawX), Math.round(ev.rawY))
        if (!isPointInsideViewBounds(view, touchPoint)) {
            dismiss()
            snackbar = null // set snackbar to null to prevent this block being executed twice
        }
    }

    // call super
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
}

/**
 * Defines bounds of displayed view and check is it contains [Point]
 * @param view View to define bounds
 * @param point Point to check inside bounds
 * @return `true` if view bounds contains point, `false` - otherwise
 */
private fun isPointInsideViewBounds(view: View, point: Point): Boolean = Rect().run {
    // get view rectangle
    view.getDrawingRect(this)

    // apply offset
    IntArray(2).also { locationOnScreen ->
        view.getLocationOnScreen(locationOnScreen)
        offset(locationOnScreen[0], locationOnScreen[1])
    }

    // check is rectangle contains point
    contains(point.x, point.y)
}
}
```

Or check out the full [gist](https://gist.github.com/and291/ce5704c4163f8dcd9d06b1ab6a9850cf)

Comment: Perfect solution for my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an `onTouchEvent` on your FrameLayout..?

I haven't tried it but i think its makes sense to me that in case of `MotionEvent` on that layout `ACTION_OUTSIDE` action should get fired.

Try the following.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  
{  

       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){  

             undoBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }  
       return true;  
}
```

Comment: Now I'm using `FrameLayout` but it does not handle touches on ActionBar

Comment: Yes, and this is also important for me. In Gmail application they managed to do that...

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible solutions.

As I mentioned in the comments you can either implement a scroll listener on your `ListView` and simple called `hideUndoBar(true)` on the slightest scroll.

OR

You can modify the `UndoBarController`. You'll notice that the undo bar is simply a `View` slap a `OnFocusChange` listener onto the `View` in the constructor and in the show method setFocus to the view.

In your `OnFocusChange` check to see if the view has lost focus and call `hideUndoBar(true)`.

## Update

I've created a Gist here https://gist.github.com/atgheb/5551961
showing how to change the `UndoBarController` to add the feature where it hides when it loses focus.

I haven't test it but I dont see why it won't work.

Comment: Sorry missed that. What is your action bar like? If you can put a custom layout in it you can put an empty linear layout in it and set an onclick event on the empty layout to close the undobar. Similar onclick of any menu items hide the undo bar.

Comment: I have large title and two icons. I would like to handle touches on them as well like it happens in Gmail app.

Comment: Well, you can create a custom layout for the title bar that has all the features you need in it. You can put your title as well as your menu items in it and that way you can register your fragment or activity as a click listener on all of them. Then in your OnClick method first thing you do is hide the undo bar and then do whatever else you want. Alternatively if you're using SherlockActionBar you can hack that library to do what you want.

Comment: Do You think that it was done like that in Gmail application? I think that there is a better way to do this...

Comment: Well the undo bar could just be a custom dialog poisoned at the bottom of the screen. That being said undobar was written by a guy who works at Google so who really knows how they did it. It could even be a transparent activity and they just finish it when someone clicks on the background.

Comment: The example I use is from guy from Google, but he implemented it in far less usable way. It can't be implemented dialog because it would require two clocks.

Answer (score 0):

```
params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

what you actually need is :

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
```

Documentation says:

> Window flag: if you have set FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, you can set this
>   flag to receive a single special MotionEvent with the action
>   MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE for touches that occur outside of your
>   window.

Comment: The disadvantage of this is that  the touch event will also get delivered to the background views.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't satisfied with any of the answers I found here. My solution is to attach a touch listener to the parent view like so:

```
((View)getParent()).setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
    return true;
});
```

Comment: If your parent view has any child buttons or other clickable elements does your onTouchLlistener will fire?

Answer (score -2):

You can get all the touch events in your `Activity` by using the below code. I guess this code would get the touches from `ActionBar` as well.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
...
// This example shows an Activity, but you would use the same approach if
// you were subclassing a View.
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 

    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

    switch(action) {
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was DOWN");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was MOVE");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was UP");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Movement occurred outside bounds " +
                    "of current screen element");
            return true;      
        default : 
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }      
}
```

Comment: Not the fact that views on top are consuming `MotionEvents`