# How do I close a floating action button menu if tapped anywhere other than the FAB menu?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have created a FAB menu, nothing special, and without using an external library. However, I would like to close it if tapped outside the menu buttons. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check when fab loose focus and hide.

```
fab.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if (!b){
                    //hide your fab
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Tried this in different combinations and it does not work as in the code does nothing. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Add dispatchTouchEvent

```
dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

     int x= event.getRawX();
     int y= event.getRawY();


         if(/*check bounds of your view*/){
          // set your views visiblity to gone or what you want. 
         }
      //for prevent consuming the event.
      return super().dispatchTouchEvent(event);    
}
```

this code from [How to handle touch outside the view in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155285/how-to-handle-touch-outside-the-view-in-android) . I think your problem is similar